# Calculation with JQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a webpage with two sliders for setting values and four radiobuttons, which serve to choose the calculation operation and a button "Calculate". How can I detect slider values and which operation is chosen, and than accordingly calculate the values and output them into label on "Calculate" button press? Note: I am totally fresh at javascript/jquery.

Code:

```
   <!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <script>
              $(function () {
                  $("#slider-range-max").slider({
                      range: "max",
                      min: 1,
                      max: 1000,
                      value: 0,
                      slide: function (event, ui) {
                          $("#amount").val(ui.value);
                      }
                  });
                  $("#amount").val($("#slider-range-max").slider("value"));
              });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
          <label for="amount">First value:</label>
          <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
        </p>
        <div id="slider-range-max"></div>
    </body>
</html>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#slider-range-max2").slider({
                    range: "max",
                    min: 1,
                    max: 1000,
                    value: 0,
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#amount2").val(ui.value);
                    }
                });
                $("#amount2").val($("#slider-range-max2").slider("value"));
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
          <label for="amount">Second value:</label>
          <input type="text" id="amount2" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
        </p>
        <div id="slider-range-max2"></div>
    </body>
</html>


<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id=operacija">
    Choose operation:<br />
    <br />
    <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
          <script>
              $(function () {
                  $("#radio").buttonset();
              });
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form>
          <div id="radio">
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Addition</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" /><label for="radio2">Substraction</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Multiplication</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radio" /><label for="radio4">Division</label>
          </div>
        </form>
        </body>
    </html>
</div>
<br />
<br />

<div id="gumb1">
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <script>
                $(function () {
                  $("button").button().click(function (event) {
                  event.preventDefault();
              });
              });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <button>Calculate</button> 
    </body>
</html>
</div>

<br />
<br />
<div id=rezultat">
    <label for="amount">Result:</label>
    <input type="text" id="Text1" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
</div>
```

Comment: In your sliders you're doing `min: 1, max: 1000, value: 0,`; i.e. you're setting initial _value_ lower than the _minimum_. Furthermore, this doesn't look like valid HTML - multiple `<html>` elements, `<body>` elements and `<!doctype ..`s. You've also included your scripts multiple times. Is this multiple pages or just one page?

Comment: This is how the page looks like: http://shrani.si/f/3L/3i/36jR3xsi/sample.png

Comment: I could just fix your HTML for you but that isn't going to help you next time; w3 provides an excellent HTML validator [**here** validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/), once the underlying HTML is valid then you can worry about JavaScript/jQuery. The main issues in your HTML I have already said in my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know many people said you should work on your HTML. And **YES**, i think so too, but I've myself learned a lot watching examples (javascript or php) when I was trying to learn. So i decided to show you how it can be done. Of course, you will learn from it, or just copy it and use. It's up to you. I just hope you will try to understand it.

```
$("button").button().click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var value1 = parseInt($("#amount").val()); //get value of first slider
     var value2 = parseInt($("#amount2").val()); //value of second slider
     var result = 0;
     var radioval = $('input[name=radio]:checked', '#myForm').val(); //get value of the radio bytton

     //calculations depending of chose of the radio button
     if (radioval == "Addition") result = value1 + value2;
     else if (radioval == "Substraction") result = value1 - value2;
     else if (radioval == "Multiplication") result = value1 * value2;
     else if (radioval == "Division") result = value1 / value2;

     $("#resultlabel").text("Result: " + result); //show result
 });
```

Whole code, with some fixes (I deleted head/html/body tags inside the divs) you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/k9rGx/9/

Remember, you need to link .js and .css files only once, in `<head></head>` tags, at the to top of the site. You don't need to do it every time you use javascript. It works for whole site.

I just hope it will help you learn something new.